# Differentiating between expand/collapse clicks in Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, accordion

I have binded clicks to headers. Is there a way to differentiate between whether the clicks are expanding the current header or collapsing it?

```
 $('.acord h3').bind('click', function (e) {

    // bind to the the header / anchor clicks
    //need way to differentiate between expanding/collapsing click here
    //only do below if it is expanding.

    e.stopPropagation();
    var x=(this);        
    alert(x.getElementsByTagName("A")[0].getAttribute("href"));

});
```

Comment: Do you mean slideToggle()?

Comment: `var x=(this);` - what?

Comment: Usually you don't expand `H3` elements, but a related DIV underneath. A HTML sample of your code would help to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `class` or `data`-attributes for detecting e.g.

```
var $el = $(this);
var isOpened = $el.hasClass('open'); // or check some data-attribute
$el.toggleClass('open', !isOpened);
```